# Stopping a Python iterator/generator after a given number of times

Tags: python, iterator

I have a generator with many elements, say

```
long_generator = (i**2 for i in range(10**1000))
```

I would like to extract the first `n` elements (without obviously parsing the generator until the end): what pythonic way could do this?

The function `iter` has a second parameter being a sentinel based on the returned value:

```
numbers = iter(lambda:next(long_generator), 81)  # but this assumes we know the results
```

So would there be an equivalent based on the number of "iterations" instead?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice

Comment: Merci, @ThierryLathuille  `islice` is exactly what I was looking for. I knew this would exist!

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following function:

```
def first_elements(iterable, n:int):
    """Iterates over n elements of an iterable"""
    for _ in range(n):
        yield next(iterable)
```

And you could get a list as follows: `first_10 = list(first_elements(long_generator, 10))`

Is there some built-in or better/more elegant way?